# Alfresco/Sharepoint and MS Office mobile app: "We don't support this authentication scheme."

Tags: sharepoint, mobile, ms-office, alfresco

I try to add Alfresco 5.0.d CE as a Sharepoint place within MS Office Mobile (Android 5).

Sharepoint protocol and online edit via Share generally works fine with MS Office desktop version. VTI is configured to run via https on port 7070 (as per http://blyx.com/2014/04/01/alfresco-tip-how-to-enable-ssl-in-alfresco-sharepoint-protocol/).

But the mobile app throws a problem: when I try to connect, the **MS Office mobile app** gives me the error: **"We don't support this authentication scheme."**

Screenshot:

[image]

alfresco-global.properties (excerpt):

```
# Authentication Chain (sorba1:sorba is my custom authentication)
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,sorba1:sorba
...
# Sharepoint / VTI
vti.server.port=7070
vti.server.protocol=https
vti.server.ssl.keystore=C:\\path\\to\\MyCert.pfx
vti.server.ssl.password=SomeSecretPassword
vti.server.url.path.prefix=/alfresco
vti.server.external.host=alfresco.mydomain.com
vti.server.external.port=7070
vti.server.external.protocol=https
vti.server.external.contextPath=/alfresco
```

I found this forum post, but it's not really helpful:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/sharepoint-doesnt-support-this-authentication/5ba8116a-6955-4486-b19e-c93affa346a8

**============ Update ==========**

A user adviced me (https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/alfrescosharepoint-and-ms-office) to use a reverse proxy (which makes sense in a way that I can use the regular https port 443 and not port 7070 as the external vti port), but not sure how to proceed from the current configuration as below:

I did setup a reverse proxy now (Apache httpd), but I still don't see how port 7070 fits in there exactly. I search for other posts, and contrary to the first blog I found, they usually use 443 as the external VTI port, and not 7070.

- https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/ssl-sharepoint-behind-ngnix
- https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/proxy-spp-apache-and-ssl
- https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/sharepoint-protocol-over-ssl
- https://github.com/marsbard/puppet-alfresco/issues/18

Now, this is my vti setting:

```
vti.server.port=7070
vti.server.protocol=http
vti.server.ssl.keystore=C:/Alfresco/alf_data/keystore/ssl.keystore
vti.server.ssl.password=kT9X6oe68t
vti.server.url.path.prefix=/alfresco
vti.server.external.host=drive.sorba.ch
vti.server.external.port=443
vti.server.external.protocol=https
vti.server.external.contextPath=/alfresco
```

and this is the virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

   RewriteEngine   on
   RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
   RewriteRule     ^(.*)$           https://alfresco.mycompany.ch/share$1       [R=301,NC,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin mlin@mycompany.ch
        ServerName alfresco.mycompany.ch

        # share is our default application
        Redirect / /share/

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/chainfile.domaincert.key.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/Star_MyCompany.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/chainfile.domaincert.key.crt

         <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>


        # SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        TimeOut 3600
        KeepAlive On

        # Einstellungen fuer den Alfresco-Tomcat
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

        # Einstellungen fuer den AJP Proxy
        ProxyPass               /alfresco       http://alfresco.mycompany.ch:8080/alfresco
        ProxyPassReverse        /alfresco       http://alfresco.mycompany.ch:8080/alfresco

        ProxyPass               /share          http://alfresco.mycompany.ch:8080/share
        ProxyPassReverse        /share          http://alfresco.mycompany.ch:8080/share

        <Proxy *>
           AddDefaultCharset on
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
       </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

How does the port 7070 configuration (ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse) fit in here? In other forum postings, I also so some RuleConditions where they check for the client to be of "Microsoft Office" beforehand. Not sure how to proceed from here now. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does it work with an Alfresco 5.1 preview install? 5.1 has replaced the Vti code with a much cleaner and newer [Alfresco Office Services](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/aos-upgrade.html), just wondering if it's solved with that or not?

Comment: @Gagravarr Not sure, I will need to give that a try. There were some issues with a previous 5.1 version in other fields which caused me to not use it yet until it's stable. That was a few months ago though, I will give it another shot.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest upgrading just yet! Pop it on a VM / spare machine / alternate port / etc, and see if AOS behaves differently enough to let this one piece work or not

Comment: Yes, of course. It's all on a non-productive environment anyway, all still in development phase.